# How can I test locally saved web page with selenium?

Tags: selenium

I have saved a web page to local file system. How can I use selenium on it without starting any web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the Location of Your Local File as the Address

As a example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/index.html")
```